# Better mood even after only 15 min of morning exercise - is this placebo or real effect?

Tags: exercise

I noticed that even **only 10-15** **min** of morning exercise at 130 BPM has a positive effect on my mood.

Would that make sense from a biological point of view ?  Or is this more likely to be just placebo effect ?

Is 10-15 min not too short to have any effect on mood ?

Related link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurobiological_effects_of_physical_exercise

Answer (score 1):

You have a better mood because when you work out especially in the morning when you can accelerate the recovery from lethargy caused by sleep (most of the times you won't even need your morning coffee ) because you release endorphins that lead to an effect known as a "runner's high" that give you a feeling of good mood.

#### Sources:

- http://edition.cnn.com/2016/01/13/health/endorphins-exercise-cause-happiness/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorphins

Comment: Right, but is there any scientific evidence for this ? I mean, can I get endorphines from only 15 min workout ? Is that really enough to have an effect ? It seems, it is for me, but I am not sure. If however is, then what is the mechanism? Is it endorphines or other chemicals ? Or just better circulation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I've found some reference that state in a very well designed study that the improvement in mood occur regardless of the time of the day[[1](http://journals.lww.com/acsm-msse/pages/articleviewer.aspx?year=1992&issue=06000&article=00015&type=abstract)].

( *Take in consideration that in this particular study the exercise protocol was only lasting 20 minutes* ).

You have to consider that some times the improvement in the mood **is even not related** to measurable parameters of exercise ( it doesn't depend on the nature of the exercise itself ).
Experimental procedures to assess exercise impact on the mood should be very precise because there are a lot of studies out there that are not so precise[[2](http://www.jpsychores.com/article/0022-3999(95)00554-4/abstract?cc=y=)].

In conclusion, to answer your question: **yes is it possible that your mood improves in such short time**. But there will not be ONLY strictly scientific clues to that; mood is not a scientific concept in close sense, and there will always be other variables that influence it other than hormones and neurotransmitters.

The second reference however, if you can get it in full paper, is a comprehensive meta-analysis on all mood studies.
You will not see in the tables the duration of the exercise protocol, aswell as the type and the intensity ( actually more influent variables ).